# How to copy hidden resource files in gradle?

Tags: ant, gradle

I am using gradle Java plugin. I see that gradle does not copy hidden (starting with .) files from test/resources directory to build/resources/test directory. Ant has an option to use defaultExcludes = 'no' to force copy of all files. How do I do that with gradle?

Comment: Can't reproduce it. Here: https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/29504250, `.lol` is copied.

Comment: I put the file inside src/test/resources/testdata/.lol . Does that work for you?

Comment: Will try in a moment.

Comment: Yes, it works. I've updated it on GH.

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying so quickly. I see that you have a Copy task. I am sing `gradle build` with java plugin. Is the `processResources` also a Copy task?

Comment: Yes, it extends copy: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/eb4d045f12dab4fa12a7da7ee99b6a70fe024a66/subprojects/language-jvm/src/main/java/org/gradle/language/jvm/tasks/ProcessResources.java

Comment: One file the Copy task seems to always ignore is a ".gitignore" file. In your test @Opal, if you throw a ".gitignore" file in your src, it doesn't get copied while the ".lol" file does

Comment: Actually, any recognized ".git*" files get ignored. I wonder if this has to do with Windows recognizing them due to having Git installed. Windows sees them as "text" files instead of "no type" files

Comment: This is due to gradle using Ant's default Exclude patterns. This can be disabled on a per-task basis: https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1883

Comment: Sorry @Veaviticus, I've just returned from holidays. Have you worked it out?

Comment: @Opal, yes I have. See my above comment. It was due to Gradle using Ant's default exclude patterns for copying files

Answer (score 5):

It is not an issue with every hidden resource file but only the ones present [here](https://github.com/apache/ant/blob/ANT_193/src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/DirectoryScanner.java#L148) are excluded by default.

You can do the following:

`org.apache.tools.ant.DirectoryScanner.removeDefaultExclude("**/.gitignore")`

For more details, refer [this Gradle issue](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1883)